# will a Child site Homepage affect main parent page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, 2007, web-part, page-layout

If I hit the "Make Homepage" button on a child site, will it affect other other pages on the site?  Will it affect the parent homepage? or other child site homepages?

Answer (score 0):

No. Clicking "Make Homepage" will only affect the current site.